# Where can I find a proof of excision for Bordism Homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, cobordism

Most sources I have found including tom Dieck's algebraic topology only provide the statement but no hint to even a method of proof. Does anyone know the basic idea behind the proof or where I can find it written out?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is in Section I.6 of Conner and Floyd's Differentiable Periodic Maps.

Comment: Ah I should clarify, from what I could find I believe this is for oriented Bordism Homology--I am looking for a proof for Unoriented Bordism Homology.

Comment: would the proof be any different?